# Python C extensions on MINIX

Tags: python, minix

I was trying to build [this package I wrote](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/uptime) (which I know to be working), first in the usual way through `distutils`:

```
# python2.7 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'uptime._posix' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error -march=i586 -DHAVE_DB_185_H -I/usr/pkg/include -I/usr/include -DNDEBUG -Wno-error -march=i586 -DHAVE_DB_185_H -I/usr/pkg/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/pkg/include/python2.7 -c src/_posix.c -o build/temp.minix-3-i686-2.7/src/_posix.o
ld -L/usr/tmp/work/lang/python27/work/Python-2.7.2 -lcompat_minix -minlib -L/usr/pkg/lib -Wl,-R/usr/pkg/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib build/temp.minix-3-   i686-2.7/src/_posix.o -o build/lib.minix-3-i686-2.7/uptime/_posix.so
ld: unrecognized option '-Wl,-R/usr/pkg/lib'
ld: use the --help option for usage information
build failed: uptime._posix (no big deal)
```

Well, fine; `distutils` is one of those modules that often break on less popular platforms. So I tried compiling the extension part manually:

```
# gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -march=i586 -DNDEBUG -I/usr/pkg/include/python2.7 -fPIC -shared -o _posix.so src/_posix.c
```

This worked—that is, it produced `_posix.so` without complaining—but, trying to import the resulting module in Python didn't:

```
>>> import _posix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: Service unavailable
```

Google suggests this is related to the ability of the OS to load shared libraries (which Python extensions are). I went looking, and it turns out MINIX didn't support shared libraries at all until [last year](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/UsingSharedLibraries), but now it should. In fact, `/usr/pkg/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h` defines both `HAVE_DLOPEN` and `HAVE_DYNAMIC_LOADING`, so it clearly does.

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MINIX does support shared libraries now, but the binary Python packages provided by `pkgin` are statically linked, which prevents them from being able to load shared libraries anyway. The only way around this is to compile Python yourself, ideally through [`pkgsrc`](http://wiki.minix3.org/en/UsersGuide/InstallingSourcePackages). All `pkgsrc` packages are built dynamically by default.

(You'll still have to build the extensions manually, too.)